# Чем синонимическая пара отличается от простых синонимов? И если просят найти пару, стоит ли искать в разных предложениях?

Tags: синонимы

ЕГЭ 2015 русский язык, есть такое задание: найдите синонимическую пару, я удивился, когда ответы были в разных предложениях, разве ответ не должен содержаться в 1 предложении?

Comment: Если можно, чуть поподробнее. Все задание, целиком. Я как раз плохо представляю, зачем тут вообще нужны "предложения" и тем более, почему это "разве не в одном?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит. Вот, например http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/907   туго-сложно

Синонимическая пара - два синонима. Если бы не было слова "пара", можно было искать 3, 4 синонима, а это Вам подсказали, что их 2, пара. и искать их нужно во всех указанных предложениях, могут быть в одном, а могут и в разных.